# Growth rates imply one function is greater at some point

Tags: real-analysis

Perhaps this is a simple question, but I cannot find any information on this online/in any books. Suppose that for functions f,g,

$$lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(f(x)/g(x)) = 0$$

I am curious as to whether this implies that at some point k, $g(x) > f(x)$ for all $x >k$?

Intuitively, the result makes sense (and is reflected in graphs), however with my limited experience with real analysis, I am having difficulty writing a very formal proof.

Comment: It doesn't in general, as the answer points out. On the other hand, if you know $f,g$ are both non-negative, as is common in practice, your claim does hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ means that for all $\varepsilon>0$, eventually $\lvert f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon\lvert g(x)\rvert$, which implies that eventually $\lvert f(x)\rvert<\lvert g(x)\rvert$ by specialisation to the case $\varepsilon=1$. It is still possible that frequently $f(x)\ge g(x)$: see for instance $g(x)=-\frac1x$ and $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$.